# Integrate hstore to timescaleDB for storing timeseries

Tags: postgresql, hstore, timescaledb

Actually, I 'm conceiving my database for storing dynamic time series for sensors data. I chose Postgres DBMS and TimescaleDB to ingest data. I have different sensors types and each sensor has different metrics that it measures. 
I give an example to make it clear:

- Sensor 1: measures **x value** and **y value** and **z value** for each timestamp
- Sensor 2: measures **a value** and **b value** for each timestamp
- Sensor 3: measure **c value** for each timestamp

We have unique table to store all that which is dynamic and in timescaleDB:

```
CREATE TABLE measures (
timestamp TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
value double precision,
sensor_id INTEGER REFERENCES sensors(id),
metric TEXT; -- this metric contains what mesures each sensor

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS _index_measures ON measures (timestamp DESC, value);
SELECT create_hypertable('measures', 'timestamp');
```

I have two options for doing that:
**Option 1:** 
For sensor 1 and sensor 2 I store the data like the following:

```
| Timestamp        | value | ID | metric  |
+------------------+-------+----+---------+
| 01/01/2020 01:00 | 5     | S1 | x value |
| 01/01/2020 01:00 | 10    | S1 | y value |
| 01/01/2020 01:00 | 1     | S1 | z value |
| 01/01/2020 01:00 | 50    | S2 | a value |
| 01/01/2020 01:00 | 10    | S2 | b value |
```

For **option 2:**

I want to use hstore to keep only one line for each timestamp where I insert all metrics as key=>value
For example:

```
timestamp; ID; metric;

01/01/2020 01:00; S1; 'x value=>5,y value=>10, z value=>1';

.
.
.
```

Which option in your point of view, you look as optimal, please?

Comment: If at all, I'd use JSONB instead of hstore

Comment: in option 2 the data will be stored as text (same is true for JSON/B) - so when you need to do calculations over your data it will be much slower than option 1 (because you must get the text-values and convert it to the right numeric type)